# Did Barron Trump wear a "I'm with Stupid" shirt next to his father?

Tags: donald-trump

[Source](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-4vtWSnCM0i8/WLUCU1tsdII/AAAAAAAADrA/HhqKVqOw0noih6aUnwrOUrTIZdhxW5E_gCLcB/s1600/Donald%2BTrump%2Bson%2Bis%2Bbiggest%2Bsavage.jpg)

[image]

This image apparently shows Barron Trump standing next to his father, while wearing an "I'm With Stupid #swedenincident" shirt.

I can't find any info. Did this happen?

I found the image in whatsapp group. In google I find large image with keyword "I'm with stupid donald trump". I got this image. I tried to find more info on the web and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

No, it is (unsurprisingly) a fake.

A Reverse Image search via Google finds the original 2016 version of it, attributed to Gustavo Caballero/Getty Images, before the slogan was edited in.

[image: 2016 version of same photograph, sans the "I'm with stupid" logo on the polo shirt]
<sub>Original image source: [vox.com](https://www.vox.com/2016/5/13/11670520/anthony-senecal-donald-trump-butler-obama-threat)</sub>

Comment: How do you know that the clean shirt version is not the one being photoshopped? Anyway, I selected yours as answer :)

Comment: Dear all: There's an [old meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/this-looks-shopped) laughing at people on the Internet who claimed something is "shopped" based on their personal authority "I can tell from some of the pixels." Please stop posting comments along these lines; they aren't welcome here.

Comment: I’d suggest adding that both pictures clearly show that the shirt in question is a Ralph Lauren brand polo shirt, which don’t come with text messages on them.  Not conclusive, but certainly indicative.